# What does this mean: "Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17"

Tags: drivers, hardware, interrupt, irq

When I run the command: `sudo lspci -vvv`, I see the following among the output:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
        Region 0: Memory at ecffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 2
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=2 PME-
        Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [d0] Express (v1) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
                        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE- FLReset-
                DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
                        RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s, Exit Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
                UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
                CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
                CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
                AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
        Capabilities: [13c v1] Virtual Channel
                Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
                Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
                Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
                Status: InProgress-
                VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
                        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
                        Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
                        Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
        Kernel modules: ssb, wl
```

There is one line of above output which says: `Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17`, I wonder what is its meaning. Does anybody know any reference which explains the details of that message and interrupts/pins. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original PCI had [four dedicated interrupt pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI#Connector_pinout), `INTA` to `INTD`. IIRC, across the motherboard they would wire them in a rotated manner so if every card used `INTA` they still wouldn't be the same physical lines. Anyway, in PCI-e, these legacy interrupts are emulated with a specific packet type; there [are no dedicated lines any more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Pinout).

This is telling you that in your current [APIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller)'s configuration, `INTA` will trigger interrupt 17 ([IRQ17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request)) to the processor when the peripheral sends one of these packets. Then the appropriate driver can register itself to be called on `IRQ17`.

Comment: On the `lspci -vvv` output, I see that some PCIs (like USB controllers) who have the same kernel driver are employing different IRQ numbers. However, some PCIs who have different kernel drivers, are employing the same IRQ number. I didn't expect this observation.

Comment: Shared IRQs is discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47306/155643). I'm studying on the topic.